# Can i use FFMPEG in a python script to combine mp4 files from a list into one file

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, mp4, concatenation

i was using moviepy but for some reason i could not get it to work ( kept telling me that i did not set up the config correctly). i was wondering if i could combine all .mp4 files in a list but still use python. this is what i got so far. is there any other ways to combine multible video files and do other things like add text to the video?

```
   import subprocess
   import os
lists = []
lists.append('E:\1.mp4')
lists.append('E:\2.mp4')
subprocess.call('ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i '+str(lists)+' -c copy outcome.mp4')
```

Comment: You need to create a [text file listing the paths](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)  and use that as input (_eg:_ `-i mylist.txt`). Get Python to save a text file with each video file path on a new text line, then write file to a location and give that loication to FFmpeg as input path.